# SQL find single value from duplicates with certain condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I realize this is probably painfully simple. Just getting late and need an explanation.

I have the table:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM employee_expert;
+------+---------+
| enum | package |
+------+---------+
| E246 | Excel   |
| E246 | MySQL   |
| E246 | Python  |
| E246 | Word    |
| E403 | Java    |
| E403 | MySQL   |
| E892 | Excel   |
| E892 | PHP     |
| E892 | Python  |
+------+---------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And I need to find the `enum` of the tuple NOT Python
Result should be `E403` since its the only one not with Python.

Tried

```
mysql> SELECT enum FROM employee_expert WHERE package != "Python" GROUP BY enum;
+------+
| enum |
+------+
| E246 |
| E403 |
| E892 |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But, obviously, it just returned all the `enum`s...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is the `not in` operator:

```
SELECT DISTINCT enum
FROM   employee_expert
WHERE  enum NOT IN (SELECT enum 
                    FROM   employee_expert
                    WHERE  package = 'Python')
```

Comment: YES. Thank you very much. Had tried the NOT IN but not with a subquery.

Comment: (On a properly indexed table, this is the slowest of the 3 solutions provided - just saying)

Answer (score 2):

A `NOT IN` will exclude a subset of data with a specific exclusion criteria:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(enum)
FROM employee_expert
WHERE enum NOT IN
(SELECT enum FROM employee_expert WHERE package = 'Python');
```

`Distinct` will exclude duplicates. [Sql Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c65e2/2)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can only accept 1. Couldn't tell if you or Mureinik was first to answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think that a `NOT EXISTS` can be faster than `NOT IN`

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c65e2/12)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE employee_expert
    (`enum` varchar(4), `package` varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO employee_expert
    (`enum`, `package`)
VALUES
    ('E246', 'Excel'),
    ('E246', 'MySQL'),
    ('E246', 'Python'),
    ('E246', 'Word'),
    ('E403', 'Java'),
    ('E403', 'MySQL'),
    ('E892', 'Excel'),
    ('E892', 'PHP'),
    ('E892', 'Python')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT enum 
FROM employee_expert ee1
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 
 FROM employee_expert ee2 
 WHERE ee1.enum = ee2.enum AND ee2.package = 'Python')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c65e2/12/0)**:

```
| ENUM |
|------|
| E403 |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.enum 
           FROM employee_expert x 
           LEFT 
           JOIN employee_expert y 
             ON y.enum = x.enum 
            AND y.package = 'Python' 
          WHERE y.enum IS NULL;
```